# Tool settings in maya with python

Tags: maya

I would like to know how can I enable some settings in the tool settings when I run my python script.

I would like to enable "Camera Based-Selection" when my script starts..
I can't find anything about this in the reference page of maya.

Can someone help me please ?

[tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itmu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turn this on and off with the [selectPref](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/selectPref.html) command.  To enable it you'd call

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.selectPref(useDepth=True)
```

And turn it off with

```
cmds.selectPref(useDepth=False)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !

Comment: don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they work for you - that way the next google searcher knows it's the answer to the question.  :)